# workaround for cross domain on ec2 clouds

Tags: domain, amazon-ec2

I have 2 ec2 server instances - i1 and i2.

If i1 serves a page, and that page has to make queries to i2 without i1's knowledge, how do I do it ?

Is it possible to avoid cross domain calls ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the internal EC2 network for this. The eth0 IP address is reachable within EC2 if you doesn't filter it with the firewall. It is not necessary to initiate a cross domain call. I hope it helps.

Comment: Do you mean the "Private IP" ?

I know instances can communicate between themselves, but I want the page at browser to communicate with instance..

Please explain how this is achieved.. ?

Comment: If you want the user to use i1 and i2 just construct the html and use URLs from both of them.

Comment: I dont want user to know about i2, the javascript in the page shall be getting data from i2 directly.. And there is no html served from i2, only json

Comment: So why don't you implement AJAX and call i1 function which gets the data from i2? Btw. you original question is really vague...